# How do I make drawString() text bold?

Tags: java, graphics, drawstring

I have a `drawString()` method in my `paintComponent` method. Is there a way to make the text drawn by the `drawString()` **bold**? Also, is there a way to make the text bigger? I would like to avoid using `JLabel`s, unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to documentation of `drawString`:

> Draws the text given by the specified string, using **this graphics context's current font and color**. The baseline of the leftmost character is at position (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate system

Indeed, `Graphics` class has the `setFont(Font font)` method available:

```
g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 16));
```

Comment: You could use g.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD) if all you wanted to do was change the font style of the current font...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Excellent, this is what I am looking for. You should have written your answer here. Will +1 without hesitation.

Comment: In case this is not clear to others, `g` is the canvas. If, for example, you're overriding `public void paintComponent(Graphics canvas)`, then you'll want `canvas.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 16));`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the font before drawing the text.

```
g.setFont(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are methods:
    setFont(Font) - Method in class java.awt.Component
    Sets the font of this component.
    setFont(Font) - Method in class java.awt.Container
    Sets the font of this container.
    setFont(Font) - Method in class java.awt.Graphics
    Sets this graphics context's font to the specified font.